# How to update after GitHub pull request is merged?

Tags: ios, git, github, version-control

I have an issue understanding the work flow on GitHub.

1. First I fork someones repository.
2. I clone the repository locally( on my computer)
3. I create a branch called Sample101 and make changes
4. I push branch Sample101 to my GitHub account
5. I create a pull request
6. The person I created a pull request Merges Sample101 Branch to his Master Branch.

The question is, How do I update my forked/clone after that person merges/updates his master branch? I just want my master copy to be up to date.

Comment: If the owner of the repo merges it, you just clone his master repo. How you do that depends upon whether you're using Carthage, CocoaPods, or manually synchronizing/cloning.

Answer (score 1):

In your local repository cloned from your Github repository (which is the fork you have push rights), add the remote for the original repository

```
git remote add upstream <original remote url>
```

Now pull, or fetch merge, whichever you're more comfortable with

```
git checkout master
git pull upstream master
```

Now push up to your fork

```
git push origin master
```